# How do i get my website appearing among google search results

Tags: html, css, github, frontend, google-search

I used github to host my website but now, if i do not add github.io, my website name wont be displayed among the various website seaarch result, even after adding part of my website name.

Why is this?

Comment: question is not clear, please add more context. "if i do not add github.io" add to where? and "after adding part of my website name" to where? can you give examples? exact search queries that should give results but are not. do you have any example (for other github sites) that works the way you want for your site?

Comment: I mean, if i search for my github website online without writing the full url, shouldn't i see it among the search results displayed by google?

Comment: well, in that case, this is not related to GitHub. Any site published in any URL has the same SEO concerns and solutions, and usually, it takes time and actual visitors to be recognized. You can have a robots.txt and backlinks from other sites will help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your website to be accessable from a search other than git hubs you need to...

1. purchase a domain, from a domain provider. Namecheap and GoDaddy our two examples of places that sell domains.
2. After that you need to use a hosting provider to host your code I recommend hostinger as they have easy-to-use git hub integration.
3. You will point the domain that you bought to hostinger and then people will be able to see your website if they go to the domain you bought.

Comment: No, no, i want the github domain name there, what i'm trying to understand is how can i get my website displayed among google search results that comprises of relevant to least relevant, even though its a github website.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to get SEO on a git hub page if you figure it out lmk, best of luck.